# Checkout a single file so that history is retained

Tags: git, github

My aim is to create a new github repo, containing some files from a repo that I have forked (and then effectively forked within my own github, using http://deanmalone.net/post/how-to-fork-your-own-repo-on-github/

I've found that in my repo, if I move files around so that they end up like I want them, the git history is removed (well, normally, and even when it isn't, github doesn't show the history until you go back to the parent commit - so all the people who actually did the work aren't listed as contributors - which I'd really like to avoid).

So, I tried doing a sparse checkout

```
git init
<set remote>
git fetch
git checkout origin/master -- python/file.py
```

but this creates `python/file.py`, rather than `file.py`, which is what I need. I obviously can't mv the file, because that has the same problem I found at the beginning.

I see two options, but haven't found how to achieve either

- is there a way to save `python/demo.py` into the current directory using `git checkout` or some other way I haven't found? (`git archive` won't work)
- can I set a new remote URL from a subdirectory? i.e. cd into `python` and then set the remote so that only `file.py` is committed into my repo?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Git, history *is* commits; commits *are* history.  There is no such thing as "file history".

It's true that `git log -- somefile.py` shows you the history that affects `somefile.py`.  But the *way* it does that is to look at *all* the commits, starting from the current one, working backwards one commit at a time.  At each commit, it diffs the *parent* commit against that commit.  Did `somefile.py` change between parent and child?  If so, *print* the commit.  If not, print nothing.  In either case, continue on to the parent commit.

(Things get a little tricky at merge commits, which by definition have more than one parent.  Here Git defaults to following whichever parent *didn't* change `somefile.py`.)

If you add `--follow` to your `git log`, Git does one extra thing: when it compares parent and child, it checks to see if the diff from parent to child says that the file was *renamed*.  If so, as soon as it moves to the parent, it starts looking for the *old* name of the file.  But you're still looking at some subset of *commit* history, in all cases.  If you have the commits, Git will look at them, and print some of them.  If you don't have the commits, you don't have any history.

Comment: Yeh - I get the git model (I don't _like_ it, and don't think it's intuitive, but I know I'm in the minority there!!), but I'm very uncomfortable with github showing me as the only contributor of a repo when all I've done is move a few files around but not written any code... I'm surprised there isn't a way round this?

Comment: The model is ... surprising, at least at first. It is self-consistent though, so one can get things done with it. :-) Meanwhile GitHub control the way they interact with their Git repos, including "contributor" items, but I don't know if they offer any knobs to adjust *how* they do their interpretation. (If so it would probably be something you can set via their web interface.)

Comment: Hmm, I guess this verifies that what I want to do is impossible(?) in GitHub. I don't like that a simple rename needs a `--follow` for git to realise it is _actually_ the same file, and so you need 3 steps to actually see the original contributor (did someone really think that was a good idea? perhaps there are reasons I don't understand), but _c'est la vie_...